# Move widget pyqt in layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlayout

Hi i have buttons in my code i would like when the user press insert new button it will move all the other button one row below and create a new button just under the one it was pressed  this is my code

bascily i am trying to move all the button in layout one row below and after i add the new button :

```
def Insert_Stage(self) :
    button = self.sender()
    idx = self.Layout.indexOf(button)
    location = self.Layout.getItemPosition(idx)

    x=location[0]
    z=self.Layout.rowCount()
    print(x,z)
    while(z >x+1):

        items= self.Layout.itemAt(z)
        # setting the item as widget 
        widget=items.widget()
        index= self.Layout.indexOf(widget)
        loc=self.Layout.getItemPosition(index)

        d=loc[0]
        y=loc[1]
        if y!=0:
            #widget.move(d+100,d)
            self.Layout.addWidget(widget,(d+1),1)
        else:
         self.Layout.addWidget(widget,d+1,0)
        z-=1

    stage=QtGui.QPushButton(self)
    stage.setObjectName(button.objectName())
    k=(int(button.objectName()[5:])+1)
    stage.setText('stage%d'%k)
    self.Layout.addWidget(stage,(location[0]+1),0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `QVBoxLayout` you have to use the `insertWidget()` method:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        for i in range(5):
            btn = QtGui.QPushButton(
                'button {}'.format(i),
                clicked=self.on_clicked
            )
            lay.addWidget(btn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        btn = self.sender()
        ix = self.layout().indexOf(btn)
        new_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(
            "button {}".format(self.layout().count()),
            clicked=self.on_clicked
        )
        self.layout().insertWidget(ix+1, new_btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @salaheddine If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour]

Comment: done thanks :) ,  does it work with grid layout ? because i have error grid layout dont have option insert

Comment: @salaheddine QGridLayout does not have any insert method so the solution is very complicated since it would be to obtain the buttons under the pressed button, remove them from the layout, set the new button with addWidget and re-establish the buttons removed with addwidget. With QVBoxLayout the solution is simple.

Comment: @salaheddine use `self.layout().insertWidget(0, new_btn)`, please read the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget

Comment: @ eyllanesc yeah i got it  was dumb forget that index 0 = first row thanks though that why i deleted my question after